# Can I embed a chrome extension app as part of my main AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been doing a lot of reading and studying to figure out.

I basically just want my main AngularJS application to run, but also include an embedded Chrome Extension app - in this case, have regularly scheduled alarms (using the chrome.alarm API).

I want all users of my AngularJS app to have automatic access to the Chrome extension app, embedded in the main clientside one with lots of other Angular features.

It seems like I have to manually enable my Chrome app in Developer mode on my browser and even drag my Chrome app specifically to a location in my Chrome browser. I don't understand how end users can just automatically use my Chrome app then.

I need to add here I have never really used jQuery, only AngularJS but AngularJS extensively. My AngularJS app is the frontend, the backend is provided by Rails.

Some advice would be really helpful. I hope I am not downvoted as it is strange how sometimes questions get downvoted and I am not sure why...I don't really know where else to go with this question.

EDIT:

Ok some code to demonstrate:

```
myangularapp.controller('myappcontroller', function($scope, $http) {

var delayvar = 5;

 chrome.alarms.create("arandomalarm", {delay: delayvar});


};
```

This doesn't just work as part of my AngularJS, I tried creating a manifest.json file in the app/assets folder too. As well as a background.js file there and my-chrome-app.js file. "chrome.alarms" is undefined, but I haven't enabled Developer mode yet. But still, how are end users supposed to use it if just to make me use it I need to do so much specific browser configuration?

Comment: Questions are not downvoted just to downvote, question are downvoted when they don't meet stackoverflow policy it's just that, for example, in your question you should add some code to explain what you want to do

Comment: every code is unique we could not guess, if you are precise you will likely have more answer and more precise answer if you are not precise then it's normal it's difficult to answer

Comment: I understand, but not every question really benefits from code depending on the audience and question. In this case, I didn't even know where to start developing. I did include some code so that I am hopefully no longer downvoted, and will always include code in the future. It was a contextual question and the code probably won't help most people help me in the first place.

Comment: take it easy bro, thanks for editing, i up-voted your question (downvote just mean, please edit your question to match SO rules, it's only that)
have a read at, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask i know downvote are not easily understandable at first... any way it never meant "your question is boring" or something similar it's just rules to keep site clean and usable for all !, it's not obliged to add code every time. just have a read at the page i sent you.

Comment: Think of it like this : SO is a Wikipedia page for programmers, when you post on it, a lot of professionals like you take time with your question, the minimum to do is to match SO rules and present the question As a wiki question, don't just think of an issue for your self but think of an issue for everybody... it took me time to integrate all those rules

Comment: Thanks intika, yes it would have been helpful in the past if people had explained the reason for the downvote. I read the rules now and will try to incorporate them always. I'm a female by the way :).

Comment: ok sister :) ... plus a women will take downvote personally more quickly than a men... i imagine you scarred of asking something lol... we all passed through that path, don't worry !... it's not easy for other users to explain to new user all the the time... now that i did it you can your turn do it for an other new user :) .... and as i am talking about voting an other information, on meta.stackoverflow.com vote are more likely to indicate agreement and disagreement

Comment: once you start to apply the rules and know more, then you start getting upvotes and reputation just by asking questions :)... but don't forget there is an other rules that implicate us to help also other users not just ask questions but it's somehow advanced rules... it's more like a help the community and you will be more helped

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and then at [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) which explains you how to communicate between a web page and an Chrome extension.

Comment: note that this does not answer the question regarding embedding an extension.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to automatically install a chrome extension. the user must install it from the chrome store.

you may make it easier for them to install it by providing an inline installation from your webpage. its in the official documentation and you can see an example on this page with the "add to chrome" button:

http://plusfortrello.com (one of my chrome extensions which has inline installation inside that page).

that example button is further customized to display a message instead if the user is not on chrome desktop.

if your extension also has permission to your webpage then you can also detect from your webpage if the extension is already install it (to hide the button, send messages to it and such).